# How to obtain java.lang.reflect.Type from a Scala type?

Tags: scala

Say I have a method:

```
def foo(t: java.lang.reflect.Type) = ???
```

and I want to call it on `(Int, Int)`.

How would such a call look? I've tried:

```
foo(typeOf[(Int, Int)])
```

but it doesn't seem to work as it returns a scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type instead of a `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `classOf` method of `Predef` (it's imported by default):

```
"".getClass
// Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String

classOf[String]
// Class[String] = class java.lang.String
```

Note that you should not create such methods as `foo` yourself, even if you want to call `java` method that accepts `java.lang.reflect.Type`. You could use `ClassTag`:

```
import reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def javaFoo(t: java.lang.reflect.Type) = t.toString
def foo[T: ClassTag]() = javaFoo(classTag[T].runtimeClass)

foo[String]
// String = class java.lang.String
```

As you can see on the call-side you don't need helper functions like `classOf` or `typeOf`.

#### Type erasure

As @cmbaxter noted: due to type erasure you can't get `Type` for `Tuple2[Int, Int]` - `Type` contains no information about type parameters. You'll get `Type` for `Tuple2`:

```
classOf[(Int, Int)] == classOf[(String, String)]
// Boolean = true

classOf[(Int, Int)] == classOf[(_, _)]
// Boolean = true
```

Comment: I agree with @senia here.  A `Class` is an instance of a `java.lang.reflect.Type`, so this will compile and run.  Keep in mind though, that if you use this as is, and pass in a type with generics (like your example, `Tuple2[Int,Int]`, you will not be able to derive the generic types due to erasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tagToType[T](implicit tag: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]): java.lang.reflect.Type = tag.mirror.runtimeClass(tag.tpe)

def tagToType2[T](implicit tag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): java.lang.reflect.Type = scala.reflect.classTag[T].runtimeClass

tagToType[Array[Int]]
// class [I

tagToType[(Int, Int)]
// class scala.Tuple2
```

You can cast tag.mirror.runtimeClass(tag.tpe) to Class[_] or Class[T].