# Scala TypeTag to java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, scala, generics, reflection, scala-compiler

I wonder if there are some predefined functions in scala (2.10+) to convert a scala **TypeTag** to a **java.lang.reflect.Type**.

Note that I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743197/how-to-obtain-java-lang-reflect-type-from-a-scala-type) question, but I need complete generic type information at runtime.

If it is not the case I can still implement the mapping my self as I already have custom implementations of java Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no such functionality built into our reflection library.

Comment: can you please point me to some documentation that would explain scala reflect Type implementations. So I can try to deduce some mapping logic from the scala types to the java parameterized type etc.

Comment: For the list of all subclasses of Type with examples of corresponding code, you can take a look at scaladoc, or even better at the source code: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ae6724527d2798b49e9c2cede536af48b3c9d962/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.scala#L392. I think the functionality you're about to develop will look like doing `yourType.erasure` and then pattern matching the result against different subclasses of Type.